# Cómo introducirme con la programación?

Tags: python

soy nuevo en esto de la **programación** y todo lo que conlleva y no sé por donde debería empezar, qué debería leer, qué debería aprender, etc. Espero su ayuda.

Comment: Yo empezaría por Java o PHP y viendo código fácilito !

Comment: Te recomiendo antes de eso leer el siguiente enlace para que conozcas las reglas que SO exige para una pregunta: [ask], ademas SO te invita a seguir el [tour] para que conozcas la dinamica de SO. Para mi esta pregunta debe ser cerrada ya que esta basada en opiniones, es amplia y de muy baja calidad.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Para obtener respuestas a tus preguntas en SO lo más recomendable es que incluyas suficiente información, como _¿cuál es tu objetivo?_ (¿quieres aprender por curiosidad?¿por necesidad? ¿como un hobby o a nivel profesional?) o _¿qué has intentado?_ (¿has leído algún tutorial o libro? ¿has escogido un lenguaje de programación? ¿asistes a un curso?¿eres autodidacta?). Es importante que incluyas este tipo de información en tus preguntas para tener más probabilidad de recibir ayuda útil.

Comment: @Roimer este tipo de preguntas no son adecuadas para SO ya que nunca tendran respuesta, son subjetivas, por ejmplo a ti te gusta un lenguaje y a mi otro, conllevando a mucha discusión innecesaria e improductiva, lo que se deberia hacer es reportarlo, o dar un voto negativo, las recomendaciones que das es para preguntas que son on-topic para SO, te recomiendo leer lo siguiente: [ask], [answer]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Como colocaste la etiqueta de `Python` supongo que ya escogiste un lenguaje de programación.

Para comenzar deberías hacer algún curso o tutorial básico en alguna página oficial del lenguaje que escogiste, como este en CodeAcademy en español: https://www.codecademy.com/es/tracks/python-traduccion-al-espanol-america-latina-clone-1 (ojo: revisa qué versión usan en el tutorial, para que trabajes con la misma). Este tutorial es interesante porque puedes programar directamente en el navegador, sin instalar Phyton en tu equipo: es perfecto para iniciarte.

También ten a mano un manual del lenguaje, con el que puedas consultar la sintaxis y el funcionamiento del lenguaje (http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/pdfs/TutorialPython3.pdf)

También necesitarás aprender algunos algoritmos básicos de programación, como algoritmos de ordenación de listas y algoritmos de búsqueda (puedes empezar por aquí para informarte: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo)

Comment: Gracias roimer. Me has sacado de un problema.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas están basadas en opiniones, ayudanos  a mantener la calidad del sitio no respondiendo preguntas que no estan basadas en lo definido en el [help].